# Cluster Analysis in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a table of employees' information and each employee has the following attributes. I wanted to do an analysis to find out what similarities they share among themselves and possibly cut them into 3 or 4 groups. I started with cluster analysis using `fit = kmeans(mydata,5)` and `fit = dist(mydata,method="euclidean")` but got an error message `NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(sales1, 5) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Do all my variables have to be numbers? Or I am using completely a wrong approach?

List of the variables:

```
$ GENDER: int  2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
$ HISP_LATINO_DESC: Factor w/ 2 levels "Hispanic/Latino",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ APPRAISAL_CRITERION: Factor w/ 5 levels "","GD","GN","TN",..: 3 5 3 3 3 5 3 3 3 5 ...
$ P2_RT: Factor w/ 7 levels "","HH","HL","HM",..: 4 6 4 3 7 7 7 3 3 6 ...
$ GRADE: Factor w/ 8 levels "21","22","24",..: 6 4 5 2 8 4 6 5 2 4 ...
$ ACTION_RSN_DESC: Factor w/ 9 levels "IVT-Misconduct",..: 4 4 4 7 4 3 4 4 4 3 ...
$ Generation: Factor w/ 4 levels "Baby Boomer",..: 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...`
$ Date.of.Birth: Factor w/ 38 levels "1/4/1978","10/23/1968",..: 28 6 29 15 11 1 18 3 32 8 ...
$ Age: int  43 55 49 37 48 34 35 45 43 33 ...`
$ Date.of.Hire       : Factor w/ 33 levels "1/1/2012","1/2/1998",..: 13 32 7 10 21 16 6 5 15 23 ...
$ Term.Date          : Factor w/ 30 levels "1/30/2012","1/31/2012",..: 18 20 4 29 2 1 27 25 22 10 ...
$ Tenure             : num  13.4 3.9 5 5.9 4.7 0.8 1.9 7.6 7.4 1.8 ...
$ Tenure.Category    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1 to less than 3 years",..: 2 3 3 3 3 5 1 4 4 1 ...
$ Gender_Text        : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 ...
$ Ethnicity          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Asian","Black or African American",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ Reg..vs..Non.Reg.  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Non-Regrettable",..: 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
$ lateral            : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
$ promotion          : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 1 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
$ Geo                : Factor w/ 17 levels "Bentonville, AR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 ...
$ Avg..Time.for.Promo: num  9 0 2.4 0 2.4 0 0 5.5 2.3 0 ...
```

Comment: K-means requires numeric data

Comment: So I have to turn all the factors to numbers first? Or K-means won't take any factor variables at all?

Comment: No, they need to be continuous. If the variables are all categorical, one option is to perform a [latent class analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model). Another option (which accepts both categorical and continuous data) is a [two-step cluster analysis in SPSS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fidh_twostep_main.htm.)

Comment: I dont have SPSS, but only R. So with what I am trying to accomplish, i.e. finding what's common among these people, am I on the right track of thinking using cluster analysis? Or there is something else I should be considering? Thanks!

Comment: If the goal is to separate individuals based on a variety of items, then cluster analysis will do that. You just have a large variety of both categorical and continuous variables. I would try and cut down the number based on some theoretical justification, rather than choosing as many variables as possible

Comment: R package cluster contains functions daisy() and agnes(). Daisy allows you to calculate distances between mixed data types, and agnes (or some other suitable function) would then do the clustering. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to measure the Euclidean distance of categories.  Euclidean distance is the "normal" distance on numbers: the Euclidean distance of 7 and 10 is 3, the euclidean distance of -1 and 1 is 2.

If you give your categories numbers, then you'll calculate the distances between these numbers - but will they make sense?  Say I have the category "Favourite Ice Cream" with entries "Vanilla", "Strawberry" and "Hedgehog", and I call these 1, 2 and 3.  Then R will calculate the distance between Vanilla and Strawberry as 1, between Strawberry and Hedgehog as 1 and between Vanilla and Hedgehog as 2.  But this distance doesn't correspond to anything real - the fact the distance from Vanilla to Hedgehog is twice as far as from Strawberry to Hedgehog doesn't correspond to anything in real life (people who like Hedgehog ice cream are not twice as different from Vanilla lovers as they are to Strawberry lovers).  But your clustering would be based on these numbers, and equally meaningless.

So you need a way for clustering your mixed numerical and categorical data with a more rational method.  In the R package `cluster` you have the method [?daisy](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/cluster/html/daisy.html), but it's worth reading the manual page to understand which options make sense for you.

Comment: This is a good explanation of why standard k-means is not appropriate in this case. The OP should note that there are LOTS of clustering methods, many of which might be more appropriate int his scenario

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the similarities within your data across different dimensions, you might want to use some descriptive plots such as boxplots for numeric data, barplots for counts of your categoric data, crosstabs and if required, stacked boxplots (boxplots where you compare some numeric variable, split according one categoric variable).

See:

- http://www.statmethods.net/stATS/descriptives.html
- http://www.statmethods.net/stATS/frequencies.html

That is how you typically learn about your data.

If you want to do clustering, you can do it either on numeric data only using the kmeans function, or you can use the R package [cluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/cluster.pdf) that accepts a dissimilarity matrix as an input.

Using an appropriate distance function (such as the daisy function in the above package), you can calculate distances even between mixed-type data.

But please consider if calculating a numeric distance between objects like (Dog, height: 67cm, color: black) and (Giraffe, height: 485cm, color: brown/white) is really the road you want to go down and what is your actual objective you are trying to achieve.
More often than not, people want to find clusters to predict something, in which case clustering is the wrong approach.